# Rails ENV Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have recently asked a similar question to this but as the problem has moved on slighty I have decided to create a new question - I hope this is the expected approach?

Having pushed my Rails 4 app to Heroku I keep getting an Internal Server Error Page and the error is:

**You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config**

This is happening because my .gitignore file includes the **config/initializers/secret_token.rb** deliberately.

I have installed the Figaro gem so that I could set my secret_key_base as an environment variable for added security. I have checked on Heroku that the key has been set correctly.

My code for the secret_token.rb is as follows:

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

However, I'm still getting the same issue.

Can anyone help???

Comment: that line of code is never going to run on heroku since the file has been git ignored - it does not exist on the server. Why do you need to gitignore the file? you are using ENV so no reason to ignore?

Comment: yeah thanks I spotted that about 10 minutes after I posted this ha ha silly mistake!

Answer (score 10):

I did something simlilar to you that worked, but didn't use Figaro. I based it off [this blog post](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/)

In summary, here's what I did:

1) remove config/initializers/secret_token.rb from your .gitignore

2)  Use this code for your secret_token.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
  ('x' * 30) # meets minimum requirement of 30 chars long
else
  ENV['SECRET_TOKEN']
end
```

3) commit and re-push

4) set Heroku env variale like:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_TOKEN=12345.....
```

Worked as soon as Heroku restarted after the config set.

Answer (score 6):

You can set environment variables on heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

You need to set SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable for heroku with this command:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=value
```

Comment: I have already run rake figaro:heroku which automatically sets this value on Heroku - as it mentions in the question I have checked on Heroku that this value exists but I'm still getting the problem

Comment: @tommyd456 can you try connecting heroku rails console and checking this config:

heroku run rails console

> Rails.config.secret_key_base

Comment: Hi yes I have done that already with "heroku config" and the SECRET_KEY_BASE env variable is right there

Comment: Checking variable with "heroku config" is ok but I still not sure that rails reads the variable correct. If you connect to rails console of heroku you can check this also.

Answer (score 1):

This may help folks using Rails +4.1:

"When deploying a Rails 4.1+ app, Heroku will specify a SECRET_KEY_BASE on 
your app by default." (https://blog.heroku.com/container_ready_rails_5)

In other words you won't have to do anything. You can omit secrets.yml (the standard version that is) from your .gitignore file without fear of losing any production related secrets.